# How to Display Emoticons/Emoji in Snackbar or Toast / Textview

Tags: android, unicode, toast, android-snackbar

I am trying to add emoticons/emoji in Snackbar/Toast notification. Do this emoticons need to be image resource or Unicode character. I am getting string output when i use unicode character from following website [Unicode Character Website](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode).

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), \U+1F601 + "Done", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After cross referencing Supported Unicode Sequences as well as the Visual Unicode Database I realized that \u1F601 was a 32 bit Unicode representation, and the 16bit representation can be set like :

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Smileys = " + ("\ud83d\ude01"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Change the last digit of `("\ud83d\ude01")`unicode to change the smiley

Refer these links

http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#note1

http://www.charbase.com/1F601

Comment: Thank You for your response . On further digging your answer, i was able to get unicode for more emoticons.

Comment: We had issues with this on pre-Marshmallow devices. Does anyone know if this only works on Marshmallow and Nougat?

Comment: It works fine on pre-Marshmallow  devices as well. I have tested on KitKat.